# Deploy react + node.js project to IIS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, iis, backend

I managed to deploy only the frontend (ran build command and added a site with the built folder path to IIS), I saw that iisnode is required in order to make it work..

How can i deploy the backend aswell into the IIS?

Comment: React web app deployment usually does not need Node.js at all, unless you want server side rendering. Anyway, if you want to deploy Node.js based app there, you need either HttpPlatformHandler or iisnode, though the latter hasn't been well maintained for years. Stack Overflow isn't a place for tutorials, and you should go to search engines.

Comment: This link should help you: [https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode).

Comment: @LexLi This is a full frontend and backend project, and trust me ive tried to look for tutorials, i found nothing helpful so this is why i'm asking for help.
if you're here for arguing don't replay.

Comment: I fully trust you that you have tried to look for tutorials, but I have also trusted that you didn't really go through the right resources. Like I commented, HttpPlatformHandler is rather simple to use, and [I wrote about it](https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/). Everyone comes here to ask for help, and I did offer my assistance from the minute I wrote that comment unless you didn't get it.

Comment: @samwu hi, i've looked into it and followed the steps but it still wont work - i get error 500.19 - internal server error.

Comment: @LexLi I followed the steps you mentioned above, still getting 500.19 Internal server error..
tried to mess a bit with the web config but still nothing..
Do I have to deploy twice the backend folder and the frontend folder as two different sites?
or its like heroku for example where you build your frontend folder and put it inside public folder in backend?

Comment: Can you post detailed error information about 500.19? We need more information to troubleshoot the issue, and this link about 500.19 may help you: [HTTP Error 500.19 - internal server error when you open an IIS Webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage).

Comment: There are too many causes of 500.19 errors if you ever check out search engines. Update the question to include at least the full error page, or there isn’t much to discuss.